# How to write this equation with sympy and sigma and mutiple?

Tags: python, math, sympy

How to write this equation with sympy and sigma and mutiple? How to use sympy Printing to do this?

sum of X squared index i, the  with i ranging from 1 to 50 divided by sqrt sigma of de x index i, a .

or

sigma of de x index i, a with i ranging from 1 to 50 multiply with sigma of de x index i, a divided by sqrt sigma of de x index i, a

∑x**2i,a * ∑xi,a sqtr(∑xi,a)

printing latex formule or equation

Comment: Hello! Can you share what you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: import sympy sigma('x ' ** 2 )index(a i)  * sigma('x') index(i) sqtr (sigma('x' ) index(i, a)

Comment: Are you confusing `sympy`  (symbolic math) and `simpy` (simulation)?  Do you only want to use it to create a latex equation?  Or do you also need symbolic manipulations? You might want to google for "online latex equation editor".  Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66590356/edit) the question and add your code there, not in the comments.

Comment: Use create a latex equation

Comment: "... divided by sqrt sigma..." But there is no division neither in your formulae, not in your code.

Comment: `\frac {\sum_{i=1}^{50} x_i^2a } {\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{50} x_ia}}`